# What is a BindAsync method with two params in the IBinding interface

Tags: .net-core, azure-functions, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

In the Azure WebJobs SDK, we have the `IBinding` interface. This interface has a method `BindAsync` with two params, but I can't understand what is the first param `object value` and when this overload method will be called.
The same question related `ITriggerBinding` interface.

I have tried to find the answer in the SDK code source. I know that `BindingSource` contains a dictionary of parameters where the key is an argument name and value is an argument value that will be provided to the `BindAsync` method, but I cannot understand what these arguments are and where they come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## UPDATE

**IBinding.BindAsync Method**  Returns `Task<IValueProvider>`.

*The usage of IBinding.BindAsync.*

[Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Bindings.IBinding.BindAsync(Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Bindings.BindingContext)](https://www.csharpcodi.com/csharp-examples/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Bindings.IBinding.BindAsync(Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Bindings.BindingContext)/)

## Sample Code

```
public async Task BindAsync_String()
{
    ParameterInfo parameterInfo = GetType().GetMethod("TestStringFunction").GetParameters()[0];
    HttpTriggerAttributeBindingProvider.HttpTriggerBinding binding = new HttpTriggerAttributeBindingProvider.HttpTriggerBinding(new HttpTriggerAttribute(), parameterInfo, false);

    HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://functions/myfunc?code=abc123");
    request.Content = new StringContent("This is a test");
    request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/text");

    FunctionBindingContext functionContext = new FunctionBindingContext(Guid.NewGuid(), CancellationToken.None, new TestTraceWriter(TraceLevel.Verbose));
    ValueBindingContext context = new ValueBindingContext(functionContext, CancellationToken.None);
    ITriggerData triggerData = await binding.BindAsync(request, context);

    Assert.Equal(0, triggerData.BindingData.Count);

    string result = (string)triggerData.ValueProvider.GetValue();
    Assert.Equal("This is a test", result);
}
```

From sample code(**HttpTrigger**), you will find `request`, `context`. They are two params in `BindAsync`. You will know the usage of `BindAsync`.

Comment: I figured this out about the `ITriggerBinding`. In the `ITriggerBinding`, the first param (value) is information about request/message, but what about the `IBinding`?

Comment: @ArtemShazhko I have updated my answer, you can click the link I provide and check the sample code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Now I understand everything. `Value` is information about the request that inits the trigger. If the trigger binding failed to return the data binding, then the parameter binding is used and the same request information is passed as the `value`. This is done in order to get the value, which will be the parameter passed to the function.